# Regex for exact string

Tags: regex

I often get emails like:
"Bla bla bla D͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏i͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ A͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏m͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏a͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏z͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏-K͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ w͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏u͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏d͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ g͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏s͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏p͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ bla bla bla" from different email addresses.

My email app (fairemail) is able to delete emails by regex.

Now I try to get a regex pattern that match:
D͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏i͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ A͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏m͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏a͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏z͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏-K͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ w͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏u͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏d͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ g͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏s͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏p͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏
I have played with regex101 for several hours without any luck. Could somebody help a regex noob.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this one

```
^.*D͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏i͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ A͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏m͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏a͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏z͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏-K͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ w͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏u͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏d͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ g͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏s͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏p͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ .*$
```

or

```
.*D͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏i͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ A͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏m͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏a͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏z͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏-K͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ w͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏u͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏d͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ g͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏sperrt.*
```

or

```
/(.*(?:De͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏i͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ A͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏m͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏a͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏z͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏-K͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏n͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏t͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏o͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ w͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏u͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏r͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏d͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ g͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏e͏͏͏sperrt).*)/gm
```